# Tools to show spills in a c code

Tags: c, assembly

Is there a tool to where I have spills in my c code?

I mean see what block of code potentially make a register move to memory.

EDIT: what is a spill:

In the process of compiling your code at some point you will have to do register allocation. The compiler will do an interference graph ( "variables" are nodes and they are connected if they are alive at the same time ). From this point there is a linear process that will do graph coloring: for each variable assign a register that wont interfere with other variables... If you don't have enough register to color the graph the algorithm will fail
and a variable(register) will be spilled ( moved to memory ).

From a software engineering point of view, this mean you should always minimize a variable live so you can minimize the chance of having a spill.

When you want to optimize code you should look for those kinds of things since a spill will give an extra time to read/write memory. I was looking for a tool or a compiler flag that could tell me where is spill so I can optimize.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware of no such tool.

Because decisions about spills vary from compiler to compiler, and version of the compiler and even by settings within a given version of a given compiler, any such tool would have to be tightly coupled to a compiler and would likely only support one.

On the other hand, you can always look at the generated assembly yourself and see if a given variable is spilled or not.

Comment: Well a tool that could work with the compiler and its assembly output to automate a good part of the process would sure be very nice.

Comment: @R. Yeah you got my point. I could look the assembly code but I will have to analyze to find the variable/block of code that caused the spill. I think spill is caused by two things, live of variables and the amount of register. You could have a long function with variables with long live range that you could be refactor to have less spill.

Comment: @Guillaume Massé: you can always refactor your functions to reduce the chance of spills...but the compiler's optimizer is likely to do a good job anyway (and if it doesn't, get a better compiler).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: haha that's what my compiler teacher said. I think if you want to optimize a function without writing everything in assembly it would be great to have tools like a "spill detector". I was wondering how knowing the compiler process could help me produce better code. But the teacher said that the recent compilers does all the job :-(.

Comment: @Guillaume Massé Your teacher is a little too optimistic, or has never worked with a certain major electronics manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally either disassemble or compile to assembler instead of an object.

For specific compilers like gcc and llvm (where you have the source and can easily re-build the compiler), modify the compiler to print some sort of output to indicate how many times it had to spill, as you call it, to memory.  Perhaps as you find the register allocation routine, you may find that the compiler already has such output.  Personally I just disassemble or compile to assembler.

A generic assembler analysis tool is possible, but is it worth the effort?  You would want to know where function/optimization boundaries are.  You would want to distinguish volatile variables, or hardware registers where the write to ram was intentional.  You could just look for stack based writes only.  Or look for cases where there is a write to the stack that is not a push, where the register is destroyed on the next instruction.  Actually it would be pretty easy to search for writes to a stack pointer relative address, with the next instruction destroying the register, with that stack based relative address being read back in a relatively nearby execution path where the stack frame has not been cleaned up in that execution path.  Do I know of such a tool? Nope.